# bash scripts not working properly after copy

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have bash scripts that running well. let say /usr/local/app1/aaa.sh

I copied over to /usr/local/app2/aaa.sh

if I run it from app2, it throws out error msg below

```
: command not foundts.sh: line 10:
: command not foundts.sh: line 17:
: command not foundts.sh: line 19:
: command not foundts.sh: line 26:
: command not foundts.sh: line 30:
```

it also happens when I copy over to my local desk and then copy back to /usr/local/app3/aaa.sh.

but somehow when I copy over to other server with scp. it works well.

Can anyone help me to understand what's going on?

Thanks

Comment: Are there any scripts local to `/usr/local/app1/` that are called from `aaa.sh`? If so, when you move aaa to another directory, it'll no longer have direct access to those scripts, so you'll need to copy them over as well.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have a relative (rather than absolute) reference in your code to foundts.sh.

I'm guessing that foundts.sh is another custom script that exists in the same relative directory on your server as on your local box say, and is referenced accordingly, say `./foundts.sh` rather than `/usr/local/app2/foundts.sh`.

When you move the calling script to a different folder the relative path no longer points to the file's actual location.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like the copies of your file have DOS/Windows-style line endings (carriage return followed by linefeed) rather than unix-style line endings (just linefeed); this confuses the shell a great deal, since it thinks the carriage returns are part of the commands (causing command not found errors) and also giving garbled error messages.

You can check by printing the script files with e.g. `cat -vet /usr/local/app2/aaa.sh` -- if the lines end with "^M$" it has DOS/Windows endings, if they end with just "$" it has unix endings.

Exactly how are you copying the script?